# How to solve: IndexError: image index out of range

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm newbee in python and trying to get every 80th pixel in 80th row, here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image


im = Image.open("UIC.bmp")
size = (list(im.size))  #  size is 1200x800
pixel_row = []
for y in range(0,1200, 80):
    print(y)

    for x in range(0, 800, 80):
        print(x)
        cordinate = x, y
        pixel_row.append(im.getpixel(cordinate))


print(pixel_row)
```

After it's done, I decode text using the code:

```
print(pixel_list)

decode_list = []
for i in range(len(pixel_list)):
    decode_list.append(chr(pixel_list[i] - 100))

decode_text = ''.join(decode_list)

print(decode_text)
```

It gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/Desktop/projects/BariySatarov/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    pixel_row.append(im.getpixel(cordinate)[2])
  File "/Users/apple/Desktop/projects/BariySatarov/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1358, in getpixel
    return self.im.getpixel(xy)
IndexError: image index out of range
```

Don't understand how to figure it out, because I get the same range as the range of the picture.

P.S. Tried to put range(0,1199, 80) and range(0, 799, 80), it doesn't work

Comment: Can you please add the picture?

Comment: Probably something simple. Maybe size is not actually 1200x800 or coordinates must be exchanged.

Comment: @Vikas P picture is bigger than 2MB, so I can't paste it in question

Comment: @Trilarion I checked the size, it's 1200x800, don't know about the second (coordinates must be exchanged)

Comment: are you sure it is x,y. Your first loop gives y

Comment: @Vikas P and the second loop gives x. The main thing is when I put this code in try/except mode, it works but get not all pixels, some of them are missing. So the coordinates I think correct

Comment: @Nikolas when I changed `coordinates = y, x ` it worked for me. Put only the last line in the try/exception block.

Comment: @Vikas P yeah it worked, but gave me wrong pixels :D
I'm making a quiz "Hiding a text message in an image"(The pixels that are of interest are every 80th pixel in every 80th row). So before, I got mostly all text, when I changed x and y in coordinates, it gives just a number of simbols, so it's wrong.

Comment: @Nikolas For hiding text messages also are you using the same scenario? I meant coordinates are x,y?

Comment: @Vikas P no, after this loops I get a list, and then I decode it, just working with a list

`for i in range(len(pixel_list)):
    decode_list.append(chr(pixel_list[i] - 100))

decode_text = ''.join(decode_list)`

Comment: You can extract the pixels by converting this to an numpy array and etracting `arr[::80,::80]`.

Comment: @Nikolas Can you please add the code that adding the message to the image, encoding message code?

Comment: @ Vikas P sure, added

Comment: @Jan Christoph Terasa Not sure I understand correctly how to make it, but I will try, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Nikolas See the answer. You can also upload the picture in PNG format, which will probably not exceed the file size restrictions.

Comment: @Nikolas Not this, encoding code. How you are hiding the message inside the image? Or you are getting it from somewhere else?

Comment: @Nikolas Your image is grayscale I presume, i.e. does not have RGB tuples for colors?

Comment: @Vikas P I don't have it, I got this image from web with quizzes for python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use numpy and array indexing for this:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


im = Image.open("UIC.bmp")
arr = np.array(im)
pixel_row = arr[::80,::80].flatten()
```

Comment: Glad it worked. If you want to continue working with images, numpy can be very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change between x and y.

x means column, not row.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the first loop is about height, so it's 'y', the second is about width, so it's 'x'. Or you mean another thing?

Comment: if the siz it's "size is 1200x800", so 1200 it's the width.